Primary Alcohol with KMnO4
I recently came across a article in which when a Primary alcohol when treated with KMnO4 with dil.H2SO4 gives aldehyde.

But during the class, I was taught that this reaction gives carboxylic acid. Among these two which one is correct and why so?

Well, these are indeed bad examples. KMnO4 and Jones r. are too harsh to prevent further oxidation to acid.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_with_chromium(VI)_complexes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarett_oxidation

This will only give the carboxylic acid if the aldehyde is present to be oxidised. The alcohol to aldehyde would be quick whereas the aldehyde to carboxylic acid will be a relatively slower process. The reaction scheme mentions the aldehyde is removed as it forms, which means the reaction won't proceed further along the oxidation path to the acid. This will likely be the reaction conditions for a specific alcohol and wouldn't be a generic approach to forming aldehydes as you are relying on distillation and using an excess of the alcohol (so would be wasteful as well).

You would get the carboxylic acid. Oxidation of a primary alcohol proceeds first through the aldehyde which is in equilibrium with the hydrate. The hydrate can then be oxidised further to the carboxylic acid.
Under some conditions, the final oxidation can be prevented and the aldehyde can be isolated using a milder oxidation such as PCC.
Here you are using the Jones reagent, which is a strong oxidiser and so will go all the way to the acid.
